# Simple CouchDB + jQuery mobile app loads list fine in desktop browsers, just not mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, couchdb, jquery-mobile, couchapp

I'm trying to write [my first Couchapp with jQuery mobile](http://grc.iriscouch.com/dictionary/_design/dictionary/index.html). In every desktop browser I tested (IE/FF/Chrome/Safari), the app functions exactly as intended. But when I try the same page in any mobile browser (Mobile Safari, Atomic, Android, Opera), the listview fails to populate.

At first I thought this might have to do with the mobile browsers handling my 
`$("#terms").listview( "refresh" );` call differently, but changing that didn't help.  I have verified that the view I am using works correctly: http://grc.iriscouch.com/dictionary/_design/dictionary/_view/byacronym.

Could someone take a look at my code and point me in the right direction?

EDIT: According to Mobile Safari's console, the script throws an error on line 34:

```
$db = $.couch.db("dictionary");
JavaScript Error on Line 34
TypeError: Result of expression '$.couch' [undefined] is not an object.
```

EDIT2: Fixed the problem by moving the `jquery.couch.js` from `/_utils/script` into `vendor/couchapp`.

Comment: Hi Sam! Welcome to stackoverflow - I'm glad you were able to fix the issue. Feel free to answer (and accept) your own question - that way when users Google or have the same issue, it's easy to find. I edited your post to help with the formatting as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that is because IrisCouch is using your User-Agent to provide Mobile Futon, since it thinks that's the only code you'll ever need.

The IrisCouch team have been advised of this ill decision and are working on a solution. The real workaround is either:

1. Copy those files locally (like you did), but then you'd waste your own diskspace and lose any auto-updates they are doing
2. The suggested solution from CouchDB is to actually go into your Configuration page and change the `httpd/mobile_futon` property to `FALSE`